# How can I find the union of two sorted arrays using pointers?

Tags: c++

I have created a union function to find the union of the two sorted arrays which will be passed in. Can someone please tell me why this is printing an array of all 0's?

Here is the whole program I have coded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int test_array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int test2_array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9};
int size_1 = 10;
int size_2 = 10;

template <typename T>
T* union_func(T *P1, int size1, T*P2, int size2) {
    T* result_new = new T[size1 + size2];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < size1 && j < size2)
    {
        for(int i =0 ; i < size2; i++) {
            if(*P1 == *P2){
                *result_new = *P1;
                *P1++;
                *P2++;
            } else if(*P1 > *P2) {
                *result_new = *P2;
                *P1++;
                *P2++;
            } else {
                *result_new = *P1;
                *P1++;
                *P2++;
            }
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return result_new;
}

int printArray(int *ptr, int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", ptr[i], " ");
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << union_func(test_array, size_1, test2_array, size_2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << printArray((union_func(test_array, size_1, test2_array, size_2)), size_1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it step-wise?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union

Comment: Not the solution for your problem. But your second is array is not sorted.

Comment: I can't find any increment of `result_new`. Also, you shouldn't increment both `P1` and `P2` pointer in all branches.

Comment: Please note that `*P1++;` is equivalent to `*(P1++);`, so that the pointer is incremented after beeing dereferenced, but there's no need to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

First some minor problems:

1. your second array is not sorted
2. you have memory leak in your code
3. the union array size is not `size1`
4. your `printArray` function returns nothing, better changing its return type to `void`
5. `printArray` function do the printing itself, no need to pass it to `cout`

And about your code:

1. you keeps writing into `*result_new`, which is the first element of the combined array
2. if the two elements you're comparing is not equal, you should not increase both pointers (`P1` and `P2`)
3. two sorted array might have different size, so `i++; j++;` might leave some elements in the longer array not processed.

Actually you don't need two level loop, three one-level loop is enough:

```
template <typename T>
T * union_func(T * P1, int size1, T * P2, int size2, int * size3) {
    T * result_new = new T[size1 + size2];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        if (P1[i] < P2[j]) {
            result_new[k] = P1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else if (P1[i] > P2[j]) {
            result_new[k] = P2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        } else {
            result_new[k] = P1[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    while (i < size1) {
        result_new[k++] = P1[i++];
    }

    while (j < size2) {
        result_new[k++] = P2[j++];
    }

    *size3 = k;
    return result_new;
}
```

And in your main function:

```
int main() {
    int   sorted_len;
    int * sorted_arr = union_func(test_array, size_1, test2_array, size_2, &sorted_len);
    printArray(sorted_arr, sorted_len);
    delete sorted_arr;
}
```